# for loop over 2^n items bottleneck

Tags: python, loops

I am using a variation of Bayes Theorem  to update all probabilities of states based on a self defined likelihood function and user input being either correct incorrect(1, 0). Each user response is to a skill specific question (skills=a-z), which creates 2^n = 2^26 = 67,108,864 possible states that must be updated. To determine the base of the Bayes equation P(data)=the sum of the product of the likelihood and the prior probability of each state based on data must be calculated. The new probabilities are simply each likelihood times prior over this number which I have put into vector notation. This process is computationally simple but each state must be analyzed by a for loop or map function each time which creates a huge bottle neck.

Here is what I have tried: remember len(states) =67,108,864

```
def like(ans, d, match):
"""
calculates the liklihood function
:param ans: 1, 0 denoting correct or in correct response
:param d: quesiton difficulty
:param match: True if question space matches part of learning space
:return: liklihood value
"""
if ans == 1 and not match or ans == 0 and match:
    return 1
else:
    # if ans == 0 and not match or ans == 1 and match
    return 1/(1-d)

def p_s_theta(ans, d, space):
"""
Calculates the data prob and return posterior prob of all spaces
:param ans:  1, 0 denoting correct or in correct response
:param d: quesiton difficulty
:param space: learning space of question asked(a-z)
:return: posterior probability of all learning spaces
"""
def p_prime(s):
    if space in s[0]:
        return like(ans, d, True) * s[1]
    else:
        return like(ans, d, False) * s[1]
p_theta = list(map(p_prime, states))

p_t = sum(p_theta)
return np.asarray(p_theta)/p_t
```

Previously the map function was represented less efficiently in a for loop form which was much slower:

```
def p_s_theta(ans, d, space):
"""
Calculates the data prob and return posterior prob of all spaces
:param ans:  1, 0 denoting correct or in correct response
:param d: quesiton difficulty
:param space: learning space of question asked
:return: posterior probabiltity of all learning spaces
"""
p_theta = []
for s in states:
    if space in s[0]:
        p_theta.append(like(ans, d, True) * s[1])
    else:
        p_theta.append(like(ans, d, False) * s[1])
p_theta = list(map(p_prime, states))
p_t = sum(p_theta)
return np.asarray(p_theta)/p_t
```

I've also tried list comprehension and multiprocessing with no luck. My question is if anyone knows of a method to loop over millions to of states with such arbitrary calculations faster than a for loop or map? Also if anyone knows of parallel processing method for this that can handle the rest of the program overhead that is one solution I am thinking may work.

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting your functions for numpy, that should give a great performance boost

Comment: this won't have any real impact but `(ans == 1 and not match or ans == 0 and match)` is simply `ans ^ match`. and `p_prime` is just `like(ans, d, space in s[0]) * s[1]`